# hook_preprocess_field not picked up by view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-hooks

In my module I implemented `hook_preprocess_field`, and alter the `#markup` of some fields. This works fine. However, when the same field is displayed in a view, the preprocess hook isn't fired.

How can I make sure the field markup is always altered, even when used in a view?

Comment: Entity fields and Views fields are different things, they just both happen to be referred to as 'fields'. You need to provide a preprocess function/template for a [Views template](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)

Comment: @Clive, thanks for your answer. What views preprocess function to use? I'd prefer a function that can be called from any module, not just the theme. Right now I alter the markup in a hook_views_post_render, but would be better to do it earlier.